# Why is it not working? I write the command to remove these characters, but it just does not seem to work

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inIvZ.png)

This code seemed to work just fine on my Windows. But when I tried running it on my MacBook, it just does not give the desired output

I was expecting the special characters under the "Price" column to be removed.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you mind posting your code as text and showing us the desired and actual outputs so we can help you better? And what's the difference in the output on Windows and Macbook?

Comment: try `series.str.replace(pat, repl, regex=True)`

Comment: Provide code samples as formatted text not as an image(s)

Answer (score 0):

If you switch `regex=True` and use OR = | , you will not see the Futurwarning:

```
import pandas as pd

price = ['$4,000.00', '$5,000.00']
prod = ['shoe', 'hat']

data = zip(price,prod)
column = ['Price', 'Cloths']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column)
print(df)
print('\n')
print(df['Price'].str.replace('\$|\,|\.', '', regex=True))
```

Output:

```
       Price Cloths
0  $4,000.00   shoe
1  $5,000.00    hat


0    400000
1    500000
Name: Price, dtype: object
```